# What actually is a CGContextRef?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics

I've been searching around the documentation for the core graphics framework and came across this in the CGContext reference

```
typedef struct CGContext * CGContextRef;
```

What does this actually mean? Is it a pointer to a CGContext? Also when I had a look at CGColor the CGColorRef is like this:

```
typedef struct CGColor *CGColorRef;
```

What's the difference between the two?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are just shortcuts to say a pointer to a CGContext or a CGColor.

So you can write

CGColorRef myreference;

rather than

CGColor *myreference;

Comment: @user1628311 : `int* a, b` is same as `int *a, b`  * is associated only with a, not with b. So in this case space doesn't play anything.

Answer (score 0):

`CGContext` and `CGColor` are two structures; the other two, `CGContextRef` and `CGColorRef` are their respective pointer types.

It's like `typedef int* myIntegerPointer;`

Just compare with: `typedef CGContext* CGContextRef;`

EDIT:

`int* a, b` is same as `int *a, b` .

* is associated only with a, not with b. So in this case space doesn't play anything.